# natbib changes my bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing an article in `lncs` style. I would like to use natbib for my bibliography because of `\citet{}` command which comes very handy. However, when I put `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` in my document, the reference page's style changes. I have two images of the two styles below:

- Without `natbib`

[image]

- With `natbib`

[image]

As you can see, the section title is centered. The reference numbers are changed from `1.` to `[1]`. Also, the title is centered and it starts in a new page.

Comment: Since you're using numeric-style citation call-outs, I'm not sure I understand why you need the `\citet` command.

Comment: @Mico many times I need to cite in this way: 
Shi et al. [35] explored optimizing a surrogate ...

Is there any way to cite the author without natbib?

Comment: Did you consider switching from `abbrv` to `abbrvnat` (instead of to `plainnat`)?

Comment: @Mico I just changed it to `abbrvnat`. The abbreviation is now in place but the style change is not :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by adding following statement directly after the inclusion of the [natib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package:

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}
```

Source: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-formbiblabel.html